# What is the most recommened video edit software for Windows 10 with UI?

Tags: windows, video, gui, video-editing

What people mostly use today on Windows 10 to edit videos?

Mostly I need to cut scenes, adjust sound volume.

Would be benefits, if supported:

1. MKV files at least for opening
2. Compression with GPU
3. No-recompression mode to keep the original quality
4. Opening and saving with subtitles.

Comment: Lots and lots of popular editors meet those criteria. You should be more specific. E.g. about expected prize, easiness of use (beginner friendly?), etc.

Comment: @Destroy666, I had some experience with Adobe Premiere and After Effect back in end of 90th, but for this purposes my favorite was VirtualDub which, unfortunately now not supported and doesn't support many new formats. I am not sure I can provide more specifics. With "prize" have you meant "price"? In this case free software would be beneficial, but it case commercial is much better suits my needs, I can consider any reasonable price. Are you sure lots and lots editors open MKV and write subtitles and can work with no-recompression?

Comment: Well, the "no recompression" part might not be available here and there if anthing, but it depends on what the editing would be

Comment: @Destroy666, the goal of no-recompression is making cuts from the videos without loosing quality. Taking into account that most of the formats use key-frames, this is possible at least with the key-frames step as VirtualDub  does. It just copies the stream between keyframes. With this I am sure that the quality is not changed and cutting goes quite fast. Anyway, let's consider this as a benefit if possible.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org) is a beginner friendly open source video editor for Windows, Mac, Linux and ChromeOS.

It has a familiar user interface and all the common editing features expected from a video editor.

[image]

As far as I can tell it doesn't have GPU accelerated encoding.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[Shotcut](https://shotcut.org/) is a more advanced (compared to OpenShot) non-linear video editor for Windows, MacOS and Linux more aimed at advanced users.

Not sure if can do GPU encoding, but it does have GPU accelerated effects and real-time preview.

[image]

Comment: "More advanced" compared to what?

Comment: @jmizv compared to OpenShot on my other answer. Edited for clarity